# RoR Hartl tutorial - tzinfo clash on Win 64 bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 64-bit, dependency-properties, tzinfo

I'm doing Hartls' tutorial on railstutorial.org

I need to run Rails 4.0.8 on my 64 bit Windows machine. This means that I have to specify the x64_mingw option on my tzinfo-data Gem in order to fix the Rails timezone bug.

- Rails 4.0.8 needs tzinfo v 0.3.37
- x64_mingw needs tzinfo v 1.0.0
- Bundle fails with a 'No compatable version of tzinfo' error.

What do I do? I'm halfway through the tut and I don't want to have to switch dev machines now! I know the configuration runs okay on a 32 bit OS.

```
rails (= 4.0.8) x64-mingw32 depends on
  activesupport (= 4.0.8) x64-mingw32 depends on
    tzinfo (~> 0.3.37) x64-mingw32
```

.

```
tzinfo-data (>= 0) x64-mingw32 depends on
  tzinfo (>= 1.0.0) x64-mingw32
```

.

---

GEMFILE =>

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'


gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

group :development, :test do
gem 'tzinfo', '0.3.37'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]

end

group :test do
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: Try cutting out specific version requirements. Starting with rails. Let it pick the version automatically.

Comment: Hi D-side. I explicitly need Rails 4.0.8 so that I can walk through the examples without endless Google tangents. Most of the Gem versions are specific to the lessons. The 64 bit mingw on tzinfo is the real fly in my ointment here.

Comment: There really seems to be no compatible version for 4.0.8. However, the tutorial is unlikely to highlight minor version differences. I've followed Michael Hartl's book myself, on Linux though, and I removed most version requirements at some point. No differences encountered. There could possibly be major differences with Rails 5, if it existed now. Anyway, you are free to experiment with library versions without changing your code. Change versions and install the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for checking into it for me anyway, D-side. Appreciated. The 64 bit Windows port seems to be very flaky around tzinfo in general. Kills many Gems. I was hoping to find some patch or getaround, but I guess I'll just have to migrate the project over to my old 32 bit system. It's a pain in the backside is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove the dependency on tzinfo-data from your Gemfile.

The tzinfo-data gem is only needed on Windows systems if you are using tzinfo 1.0.0 or later. Rails 4.0 uses tzinfo ~> 0.3.37, so tzinfo-data is unnecessary.

The reason for this is that tzinfo before version 1.0.0 included all the time zone data it needed to operate (effectively bundling the tzinfo-data gem). With the release of version 1.0.0, the data was split out into a separate gem.

If you were to upgrade to Rails 4.1 in the future on Windows, you'd need to change your Gemfile to remove the specific version dependency on tzinfo and add the tzinfo-data dependency back in. This is because Rails 4.1 requires tzinfo ~> 1.1.

Comment: ((facepalm)) - And I've faffing around all day with tzinfo because that's the dependency Gem complains about. 

I must have added tzinfo-data back in when I was trouble-shooting bcrypt errors or something. That explains how I was able to run the server at all during earlier lessons.

Thanks Phil :)